# How to get the name of Fk column which has been conflicted using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, foreign-keys

I have table which has several foreign key columns and I need using Entity Framework to log which FKs have been conflicted during insert/update operations to get the name of the Fks have been conflicted using DbUpdateException?

Right know I am using this method to check if Fk conflict exception has ocurred:

```
   public static bool IsFKException(Exception exception)
    {
        SqlException innerException = null;
        Exception tmp = exception;
        while (innerException == null && tmp != null)
        {
            if (tmp != null)
            {
                innerException = tmp.InnerException as SqlException;
                tmp = tmp.InnerException;
            }

        }
        if (innerException != null && innerException.Number == 547)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I want to modify this method to get me the names of those Fks columns.

So how can I get that implemented using Entity Framework and C#?

Comment: Can you provide the exception message too ?

Comment: @Rainman "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Classifications_dbo.ClassificationEssentials_EssentialId". The conflict occurred in database "Mydatabase", table "dbo.ClassificationEssentials", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated" But I have noticed when more than one conflict occurs it shows me only one!!!

Comment: You can't catch all conflict statements like this because when EF encounters a conflict, it throws error for this conflict and the process is terminated.